# iOS make UIPickerView in UITableViewCell fit in one row

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uipickerview

I have a custom `UITableView` and I would like to display a picker in some of the rows. I have kind of achieved this by adding pickers to the `accessoryView`, for example

```
case 1:
    cell.textLabel?.text = "Color mode"
    let picker = UIPickerView()
    colorModeDelegate = ColorModeDelegate()
    picker.dataSource = colorModeDelegate
    picker.delegate = colorModeDelegate
    picker.showsSelectionIndicator = true
    cell.accessoryView = picker
    break
```

But the result is that the pickers expand above and below their cells, with the other alternative values and the result is a complete mess:

[image]

Is it possible to make these picker fit on one row, and display only the selected value (i.e kind of clip the visible area to the table cell). This is an example of what I would like to achieve. The last row shows in between two values as it in in the process of being changed (user is dragging)

[image]

Comment: maybe lay opaque views above and below the picker such that just the central area is visible?

Comment: You can create a custom tableViewCell with a pickerView and apply autoLayout there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I achieved something quite close by using setting the clipToBounds property of the table cell to true.